# Composition of Transformation Matrix from scaling, angling and reflecting

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I want to create a transformation matrix $T$ based off of a few things...

First, I rotate clockwise by some angle $\theta$ with matrix $A$, then I scale by some factor $k$ with matrix $B$, then I reflect about some line $l$ with some matrix $C$.

Why does $T = CBA$ and not $T = ABC$? I would think that the multiplication would follow the order, but apparently it doesn't. Why is this true?

Comment: How will $T$ be applied to transform some $X$? On left or right? If $TX$ then $TX = CBAX$ and $A$ applies first, while if $T$ acts on the right, then $XT = XABC$ and $A$ acts first.

Comment: @Weaam Of the form $T(\hat{x} ) = \hat{b}$ 
A transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: On the left. It should be clear now why, if not notice (CBAx = CB(Ax) = C(Bx') = Cx'' = x''').

Comment: @Weaam Ahh, of course!